# mipmap colour artefact in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, mipmaps

I'm using textures in OpenGL (in FLTK with c++) and am using mipmaps. I am making a multi platform project (current coding in Mac), but I don't want to use extensions in Windows so I'm not using glGenerateMipmap and so decided to do them manually. I do it, in this example for a 'floor' and a 'ceiling'. I use the following code to load the data from the different resolution image versions

```
glGenTextures(1, &ceiling_texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ceiling_texture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 8);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, ceiling_width0, ceiling_height0, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, ceiling_pixels0);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGB, ceiling_width1, ceiling_height1, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, ceiling_pixels1);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 2, GL_RGB, ceiling_width2, ceiling_height2, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, ceiling_pixels2);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, GL_RGB, ceiling_width3, ceiling_height3, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, ceiling_pixels3);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 4, GL_RGB, ceiling_width4, ceiling_height4, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, ceiling_pixels4);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 5, GL_RGB, ceiling_width5, ceiling_height5, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, ceiling_pixels5);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 6, GL_RGB, ceiling_width6, ceiling_height6, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, ceiling_pixels6);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 7, GL_RGB, ceiling_width7, ceiling_height7, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, ceiling_pixels7);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 8, GL_RGB, ceiling_width8, ceiling_height8, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, ceiling_pixels8);
```

When I use the texture I use

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,ceiling_texture);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT );
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT )

       //draw primitives with texture coordinates

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

I use the exact same code and procedure for the 'floor'.

However, for the ceiling I get a strange colour artefact (a yellow hue) in the distance where it is using the low resolution mipmaps. (see picture)

[image: Yellow artefact in ceiling]

I generated the pixel information using `glGetTexImage` applied to different versions of the same file at different resolutions that I generated by just scaling the image in GIMP. Again I did the same for both the floor and the ceiling.

When I was using `glGenerateMipmap` this didn't happen.

Why am I getting this artefact and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 1):

Urgh. Such a disappointing reason. Turns out when I was scaling the image down in GIMP it was using some strange averaging which, for the very corner pixel of the smallest resolution image (2x2), decided to just get the blue component totally wrong (underestimating it). Manually forced that to a more reasonable value and it works now.

Answer (score -1):

Wrong:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
```

Right:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_LINEAR);
```